# Disturbed digital out at 4Mhz on Arduino NANO

Tags: arduino

I've written a simple program - it generates signals over `Port D` at 4 MHz:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

int main(void) {

    DDRD = B11111111;
    PORTD = B00000000;

    while (true) {
        PORTD = 0;
        PORTD = 5;
        PORTD = 10;
        PORTD = 15;
        PORTD = 20;
        PORTD = 25;
        PORTD = 30;
        PORTD = 35;
        PORTD = 40;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the signal coming out on D4:
[image: Max Frequency]

I've modified the program by inserting NOP after each assignment to `POTRD`:

```
#define NOP __asm__ __volatile__ ("nop\n\t")

int main(void) {

    DDRD = B11111111;
    PORTD = B00000000;

    while (true) {
        PORTD = 0;NOP;
        PORTD = 5;NOP;
        PORTD = 10;NOP;
        PORTD = 15;NOP;
        PORTD = 20;NOP;
        PORTD = 25;NOP;
        PORTD = 30;NOP;
        PORTD = 35;NOP;
        PORTD = 40;NOP;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and now signal looks fine, but frequency is limited to 800 MHz:
[image]

What is the reason for interference at 4 MHz? Is there a limitation to maximal frequency on digital out? I do not really need it for some particular project, just wanted to know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted this question on arduino.stackexchange.com and it got an answer:

https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/11821/disturbed-digital-out-at-4mhz-on-arduino-nano/11830